# I'm facing a port problem in flask , how to change port?

Tags: python, database, visual-studio-code, flask-mysql

```
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

my database is in localhost 3306, but my program runs in 5015 port, if I change the port to 3306 instead of 5015 in **app.run**(`debug=true,port=3306`), it's showing the above error.

Answer (score 1):

Port 3306 is the default port for the classic MySQL protocol ( port ), which is used by the MySQL client, MySQL Connectors, and utilities such as `mysqldump` and `mysqlpump`.

So you can use some other port which isn't used by other applications.

If you want to run your Flask app in port number 80 (say), you can do that this way.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

For more details about `app.run` check this [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/).

Answer (score 0):

As you say, port 3306 is already used by your database. You shouldn't try to also use it for the app.